# Dendropy leaf_iter() error with lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, tree, iterator, phylogeny

I'm doing some phylogenetics in Dendropy:
I'm trying, following the tutorial, to traverse all the leaves of a tree using a filter (a lambda function).

Using the lambda function gives an error if the iterator is leaf_iter, but not if the iterator is any other one (for example postorder_node_iterate). What am I missing?

The traceback is some hundreds line long so I just show you an extract:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#274>", line 1, in <module>
    for node in tree_test.leaf_iter(survival):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dendropy\dataobject\tree.py", line 915, in leaf_iter
    for node in self.seed_node.leaf_iter(filter_fn=filter_fn):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dendropy\dataobject\tree.py", line 2444, in leaf_iter
    for node in self.postorder_iter(filter_fn):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dendropy\dataobject\tree.py", line 2427, in postorder_iter
    if filter_fn is None or filter_fn(node):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dendropy\dataobject\tree.py", line 2441, in <lambda>
    filter_fn = lambda x: x.is_leaf() and filter_fn(x) or None

[... line 2441 ...]

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dendropy\dataobject\tree.py", line 2441, in <lambda>
    filter_fn = lambda x: x.is_leaf() and filter_fn(x) or None
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dendropy\dataobject\tree.py", line 2537, in is_leaf
    return bool(not self._child_nodes)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

To test the problem you can use the following code, pretty much taken from the tutorial:

```
#call a bit of modules and build a simulated tree
import dendropy
import random
from dendropy import TaxonSet, Tree, TreeList, treesim
taxa = dendropy.TaxonSet(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
tree_test = treesim.birth_death(0.4, 0.1, ntax=8, taxon_set=taxa, repeat_until_success=True)

#define an evolutionary character
def evolve_char(tree, start=1.0):
    for node in tree.preorder_node_iter():
        if node.parent_node is None:
            node.value = 1.0
        else:
            node.value = random.gauss(node.parent_node.value, node.edge.length)
    return tree
#evolve the character on the simulated tree
evolve_char(tree_test)

#positive_char select the nodes with positive character
positive_char = lambda node: True if node.value > 0. else False

#iter with postorder_node_iter (no problem)
for node in tree_test.postorder_node_iter():
    print("Node %s with value %s" % (node.taxon, node.value))
for node in tree_test.leaf_iter(positive_char):
    print("Node %s with value %s" % (node.taxon, node.value))

#iter with leaf_iter without filtering (no problem)
for node in tree_test.leaf_iter():
    print("Node %s with value %s" % (node.taxon, node.value))

#iter with leaf_iter and filtering (problem!)
for node in tree_test.leaf_iter(positive_char):
    print("Node %s with value %s" % (node.taxon, node.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was a bug. Just fixed in the new github release.

I'll leave this here as somebody else may find the same problem.